# SYS account can not view all tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

As you can see in picture I am connecting to my database as SYS with the SYSDBA below

[image: SQL Developer connection with SYS and SYSDBA]

The filtered tables shown in the picture 2 seems are system tables, right, as all tables names are ended with $?

[image: SQL Developer table list in connections plus query and error]

I am wondering why SYS does not have permission to view the tables we created e.g `filetable` (as shown in the picture above). Is it because this ID does not have permission to select all tables? If yes, how can I allow the ID have permission to view all tables, including `filetable`?

Does this SYS account have FULL privileges in the database or not? I tried to use the below command to grant privileges to user but that didn't work, getting the error shown:

```
SQL> grant SELECT on filetable to user

grant SELECT on filetable to user

        *

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What I need to do is create a user and grant select permission on all tables to this user.

What I need to do ?

Comment: and what schema did you create the tables under?   Just because you are SYS does not mean you can see a table unless it is in the SYS schema or you have a synonym defined

Comment: Even if user A has rights to access table X in schema B, in the absence of synonyms, it should do select * from B.X, no select * from X. And anyone can have tables whose names end with $, not only SYS or SYSTEM

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simple run

```
select owner, table_name from dba_tables where table_name= 'FILETABLE';
```

or fallback to query below if it is not a table, but a view or a materialized view

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where object_name= 'FILETABLE';
```

than take what you see in the column `owner` and query with (substitue `[owner]` with the *owner* you see) - if the query above return no rows the object does not exists.

```
 select * from [owner].FILETABLE
```